# Regular expression replace PHP

Tags: php, regex

Whats the correct way in php to str_ireplace:

Any number[dot] Any number to Any number[dot]Any number

For example:

```
5. 1
```

to:

```
5.1
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there multiple numbers in a string?

Comment: You should look into regular expressions

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that we encourage posters here to give these sorts of questions a go. Simply stating your requirements will give the impression that you will try to get someone else to do your work for you - showing an attempt will reveal some effort, and you may even get upvotes for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to only remove whitespace between the digits.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\d+\.)\s+(\d+)/', '$1$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about it? It simply removes all spaces between number with dot then one space and another number.

```
preg_replace('(\d+\.) (\d+)', '$1$2', $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove whitespace from your string, you can use this code:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $input);
```

This will result in the described output for intput `5. 1`.

If you want to do more complicated changes, you have to define your requirements first.